# How to assign different scenes for workspaces in Blender 2.8?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, workflow, scene, workspaces

In **2.79** I could select a workspace, choose any scene and easily switch between workspaces - for example I had one scene for modeling and another one for VSE.

But in **2.8** I can't find a way to do so. It seems like scene selecting is now a global thing and switching between workspaces shares the same scene.

As you can see green highlighted part is a scene created specifically for *Video Editing*, but if I switched to workspace *Layout* - I'd still be viewing this scene.

[image]

I used to this so much, cause Blender doesn't allow to use same scene as strip in VSE.

Comment: if you mean what used to be layers then collections has replaced it a google search of collections in blender 2.8 will probably help

Comment: @J Block I didn't mean layers or collections. Whole scene, which contains everything

Comment: top of screen on the right there is the scene settings almost like 2.79

Comment: @J Block Yes, except it shows same scene for every workspace

Comment: that is if you duplicate it if you press add new scene by type and choose new it will create a new empty one. i might just have a different build of 2.8 but that's what i found

Comment: there is now an add-on for this: https://youtu.be/GV2GRKnycg4

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify (or what I think the problem is):  It's annoying to constantly change the active scene when switching between Video editing and any other operation.

**The workaround** is to use "Window->New Main Window" and use the first window for 'Video Editing' and the second window for everything else. I realize the convenience when you change the scene for Layout/Modeling/Sculpting/Animation etc. But this becomes an INconvenience for the 'Video Editing' workspace. It seems it takes another monitor to go smoothly.

Comment: Yeah "New Main Window" dedicated for special scene is currently the best solution, even for a single monitor

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for how long this option is presented in Blender (found it in 3.3.2 and 3.4), but here it is:

**Pin Scene to Workspace**

[image]

Just select desired scene and press pin icon.