# Is there a way to store a workspace with a scene & auto-recall it when changing to that scene?

Tags: interface, customization, scene

In my .blend file i have one scene called Master, which has a VSE containing other scenes in the file as strips.

While editing the other scenes i need to be working in a 3dview panel. While editing the Master scene i need to be in the VSE panel.

Is there a way to specify that a workspace with a big VSE panel 'belongs' with the Master scene, and a workspace with big 3d view panel belongs with all others, so that the appropriate layout is loaded when the corresponding scene is made active. I’d like to not need to manually change the workspace each time I switch between the Master scene and the others in the project.

(I don’t mind using scripting if it’s necessary, but i couldn’t find an ‘active scene changed’ callback in the API so far)

Thanks!

Comment: You can just create a new workspace and switch workspaces using Ctrl + Page Up or Ctrl + Page Down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be the default in Blender 2.7x, apparently they removed the function entirely, Here is a workaround:
[How to assign different scenes for workspaces in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144011/how-to-assign-different-scenes-for-workspaces-in-blender-2-8) 
He creates a new window and instead of switching workspaces, he switches windows (ALT - TAB)

Comment: ah, shame. thanks for the workaround